# I can't locate the create a new project menu in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, new-project

I recently installed Visual studio version 1.62.2_amd64.deb on my asus Chromebook using linux. I can't find the "create a new project" menu to create a new console application using c#. All I see is new file or new folder. Can someone help me with what I'm missing out to completely setup the IDE to run my codes properly

Comment: Visual Studio doesn't support Linux, it doesn't run natively, you may be able to get it to run using Wine trickery but I suggest you don't try it and just use Visual Studio Code and .NET Core, there's even an official tutorial from Microsoft [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/dotnet) on doing that

Comment: I think you mean Visual Studio Code(Not MS Visual Studio).
I always use it on linux and I've never seen the "Create a new project" option. The normal thing in VS Code is to create a new folder in your filesystem and then open it from the "Open folder" VS Code menu option.
Particulary referring to C#, the best way to work with it is following the @MindSwipe recommendation. Best regards!

Comment: VS and VSC are complete different things, VS is an IDE and VSC is an editor, VSC does not have new project menu option, you have to set it up yourself and the build of the project. I recommend you install VS Community edition in Windows